# Bootstrap Carousel bug on Firefox

Tags: firefox, bootstrap-4, carousel

I'm using Bootstrap Carousel on Firefox, not working. It works on Chrome but not in Firefox. The previous button works fine, but next button makes the slide to bug. Does anyone have noticed that?

Here is the website I'm working on:

http://br418.teste.website/~noron298/work-in-progress/site1/

You can access on Firefox and see the bug.

What could I do?

Thanks!

Comment: It is actually working for me Firefox 58.0.2 similar than chrome. Or I miss something I can't see.

Comment: It is a blank space as you press right slide button

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug of Firefox and its CSS rendering engine. There is a bug at Mozilla: [1425213](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1425213)
I think this will be fixed by Mozilla but in the meantime maybe a solution for you is following fix: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/24657#issuecomment-360552841